# Incomplete Question? - Ratio

Tags: linear-algebra, percentages, gre-exam, ratio

I have encountered the following question in the famous "5LB book of GRE" book

*If the zoo currently has 80 total birds, what is the samllest number of birds that could be added such that atleast 20% of the animals at the zoo would be birds?*

(A) 10

(B) 80

(C) 100

(D) 125

(E) 200

The correct answer is 100 and in the answer sheet it stats "If the zoo has 80 birds, which make up to 10% of the total number, then there are 800 total animal"

Can this be derived from the question or is the question incomplete?

Comment: they should have either gave 80 is 10% of total or total is 800

Comment: Clearly incomplete, either the initial percent of birds or the total number of animals must be specified

Answer (score 0):

Yep - definitely incomplete.

If you don't know either
the total number of animals
or some ration of birds to animals,
there is no way the question
can be answered.

My guess is that the test preparer
left out a phrase
and the proof reader goofed.